# Drools 6 sisu-guava conflicts with guava

Tags: maven, guava, drools

We have recently upgraded from Drools 5 to Drools 6 and have run into disturbing conflict issues.

We have `kie-ci` imported into out project. `kie-ci` brings in `sisu-guava`. `sisu-guava` changes the accessibility of some of the classes from google's guava. Unfortunately, it uses the same package name as google's guava.

Since we're working with google's guava in our project, we are running into conflicts of classes.
An attempt to remove `sisu-guava` from the project (using a maven exclusion) results in accessibility exceptions, as the kie-ci code attempt to access classes which are public in `sisu-guava` but are private in google's guava.

Any idea how to get round this.

Comment: I think you'd better ask this on one of these Drools user Google groups: Drools Setup - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-setup (click link to subscribe)
Drools Usage - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-usage (click link to subscribe)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be correct solution for all situation, but I was able to resolve this issue by excluding the susi-guava jar in my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-kie-services</artifactId>
        <version>${jbpm.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.sisu</groupId>
                <artifactId>sisu-guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: We tried that. See the second paragraph of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same problem using drools 6.2. Drools is dependent on guava 10.0.1, where as my project had a dependency on guava 16 and maven was picking the version 16 (correctly).

On inspecting the dependency tree, I find that the drools dependency on guava is dictated by "org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.0.0.M5:runtime".

There is a newer version of org.eclipse.sisu.plexus, so I added the following to my project's pom to pick up the latest version, which is:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.sisu</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.sisu.plexus</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now, there does not seem to be a dependency on guava, for drools and the problem is solved and my project can use version 16 of guava.